# How to make a tab invisible, but not the sheet that would show when the tab is selected? - Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to be able to open tabA from a button on tabB. But I don't want the user to be able to open tabA, apart from using that button. However if you set the `TabA.Visible := False` it sets the tab and the tab sheet as not visible. Is there any way around this?

My idea would be to cover tabB with a blank white image when I need tabA showing, and when I need tabB showing just hide all the tabA controls. Would this be the best thing to do for this issue?

Comment: Unlike `TPageControl` in VCL, `TTabControl` in FMX does not allow you (that I can see) to set individual tabs invisible while still viewing their pages. You can, however, hide all tabs via `TTabControl.TabPosition` and still be able to switch between pages via code ([tutorial](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Tab_Components_to_Display_Pages_(iOS_and_Android))). Or, simply have your button set `TabA.Visible=True` and `TTabControl.ActiveTab=TabA`, then set `TabA.Visible=False` again when you are done using it

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be better to make TabA a panel instead. When you click the button, hide the page control and show the panel. Or, if you want to keep it in that tab, put TabB's controls in a panel, put TabA's controls in another panel in TabB. When you click the button, hide panel1, show panel2, while all the time you stay in your one and only TabB.

Comment: @GolezTrol Actually, FMX kinda encourages use of tabs in this manner. There's even sliding transitions when switching tabs.

Comment: I think a better idea would be to put another two page TabControl inside your tab, hide the tabs and switch pages with your buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to be able to open tabA from a button on tabB. But I don't want the user to be able to open tabA, apart from using that button. However if you set the TabA.Visible := False it sets the tab and the tab sheet as not visible. Is there any way around this?

You can hide the tabs (while keeping the sheets visible) by setting property `TabControl1.TabPosition = None`. *Note! This setting makes all tabs invisible*.

So no, you don't need any images or anything else to cover either sheet.

Moving between the tab sheets can then be done in code in one of three ways:

- setting TabControl1.ActiveTab to a TTabItem
- setting TabControl1.TabIndex to the index of a tab sheet (index is zero-based)
- calling TabControl1.Next/Previous to move to the following/previous tab sheet

Example code

```
// Button on first tabsheet
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//  TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem2; // Immediate transition
//  TabControl1.TabIndex := 1;  // Immediate transition
  TabControl1.Next;  // Animated transition
end;

// Button on second tabsheet
procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//  TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem1; // Immediate transition
//  TabControl1.TabIndex := 0;  // Immediate transition
  TabControl1.Previous;  // Animated transition
end;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Sorry what was getting at when i said "However if you set the TabA.Visible := False it sets the tab and the tab sheet as not visible. Is there any way around this?", was really that I wanted to make the sheet for TabA Sheet visible, but without making the actual Tab in the TabControl visible as I don't want tabA tab showing I just want to show the sheet for tabA.

Comment: OK @Wiliam, thanks for the heads up. Yes I see now how I misread your question. I guess you do not want to have any tabs at all, answer corrected.